# How to change cells properties automatically when converting arrays to HTML

Tags: html, arrays, powershell

I'm using this PowerShell script to transfer some data to HTML file. I need to add another line numbers automatically(LP) and change the color of cell(SUM/GB) depending on the value. If is less than 20 -do nothing, when more than 20 and less than 25 - yellow, when more than 25 -red .

My script:

```
$a = '<style>'
$a = $a + 'BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}'
$a = $a + 'TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}'
$a = $a + 'TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:thistle}'
$a = $a + 'TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color:palegoldenrod}'
$a = $a + '</style>'

[int]$c=0
[int]$d=20
[int]$e=25
$computers | Sort-Object UserSurname |  Where-Object {($PSItem.Username -ne '' -and $PSItem.UserSurName -ne '')}| Select-Object -Property @{n='LP';e=$PSItem.index}},`
                                         @{n='Surname';e=$PSItem.UserSurname}},`
                                         @{n='Name';e={$PSItem.UserName}},`
                                         @{n='Desktop/GB';e={'{0:N2}' -f $PSItem.HDDUsageDesktop/1GB)}},`
                                         @{n='Documents/GB';e={'{0:N2}' -f($PSItem.HDDUsageDocuments/1GB)}},`
                                         @{n='Pictures/GB';e={'{0:N2}' -f($PSItem.HDDUsagePictures/1GB)}},`
                                         @{n='Video/GB';e={'{0:N2}' -f($PSItem.HDDUsageVideos/1GB)}} ,`
                                         @{n='Sum/GB';e={'{0:N2}' -f($PSItem.HDDUsage/1GB)}},`
                                         @{n='Size HDD/GB';e={$PSItem.HDDSize}},`
                                         @{n='Free space/GB';e={$PSItem.FreeSpace}},`
                                         @{n='Fre space/%';e={$PSItem.PercentOfTheSpaceUsage}},`
                                         @{n='Last scan date';e={$PSItem.LastScanDate}},` 
                                         @{n='Adsress IP';e={$PSItem.ipv4}} |
                                         ForEach-Object {if(([convert]::ToInt16($PSItem.HDDUsage)-ge $d) -and ([convert]::ToInt16($PSItem.HDDUsage)-lt $e) ){$PSItem -replace '<Tr>','<tr bgcolor=green>'}elseif([convert]::ToInt16($PSItem.HDDUsage) -ge $e ){$_ -replace '<tr>','<tr bgcolor=red>'}else{$_}} |
                                         ConvertTo-HTML -body '<H2>HDD Usage</H2>' -head $a | 
                                         Out-File c:\users\adminrka\desktop\report.html
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Where do you stuck? Also, an example (primary for `$computers`) would be helpfull.

Comment: I'm stuck on:@{n='LP';e=$PSItem.index}},I don;t know really how to calculate dynamically lines and put them into table. Also the code to change the color does not quite work. $computeras is the array of computers object with some extra properties made by me to help to collect the data and calculate them